# How to check if my data already exists in my database before creating?

Tags: exists, laravel-6

I am working on a Laravel 6 application for nurses and I need to create a patient. My problem is many patients can have the same address and last name. I tried different ways to check if the patient already exists, but I just have in the result that I can't have two patients with the same data. I want to check if all the information on the new patients is equal to one in the database.

I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```php
if ($patientotal = Patient::where([
    ['nom', $data],
    ['prenom', $data],
    ['telephone', $data],
    ['adresse', $data],
    ['codePostale', $data],
    ['ville', $data],
    ['infoSupplementaire', $data]
])->doesntExist()) {
}
```

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'nom' => 'required',
        'prenom' => 'required',
        'telephone' => 'required',
        'adresse' => 'required',
        'codePostale' => 'required',
        'ville' => 'required',
        'infoSupplementaire' => 'required',
    ]);

    $patient = new Patient();
    $patient->nom = $request->nom;
    $patient->prenom = $request->prenom;
    $patient->telephone = $request->telephone;
    $patient->adresse = $request->adresse;
    $patient->codePostale = $request->codePostale;
    $patient->ville = $request->ville;
    $patient->infoSupplementaire = $request->info;

    if ($patient->save()) {
        if ($request->has('debut', 'fin')) {
            $dataOrdo = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'dateOrdonnance' => 'required',
            ]);
            $datedebut = Carbon::parse($request->debut);
            $datefin = Carbon::parse($request->fin);

            $ordonnance = new Ordonnance();
            $ordonnance->debut = $datedebut;
            $ordonnance->fin = $datefin;
            $ordonnance->patient_id = $patient->id;
            if ($ordonnance->save()) {
                session()->put('id_ordonnance', $ordonnance->id);

                return ['patient' => $patient, 'ordonnance' => $ordonnance];
            }
        }
    };

    return response()->json([$request->all()]);
}
```

Comment: You can also try `insertOrIgnore`.

Comment: i tried with insertOrIgnore , firstAndNew, Exist, doesntExist  maybe i was doing in the wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did this, a nice person give me help and it's work good. Thanks a lot for the help the 1st day of the year

```
 public function store(Request $request)

{


        $data=  Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'nom'=>'required',
            'prenom'=>'required',
            'telephone'=>'required',
            'adresse'=>'required',
            'codePostale'=>'required',
            'ville'=>'required',
            'infoSupplementaire'=>'required',
        ]);
        $patientExists = Patient::where('nom', '=' ,$request->nom)
                     ->where('prenom', '=', $request->prenom)
                     ->where('telephone', '=', $request->telephone)
                     ->where('adresse', '=', $request->adresse)
                     ->where('codePostale', '=', $request->codePostale)
                     ->where('ville', '=', $request->ville)
                     ->where('infoSupplementaire', '=', $request->info)   
                     ->count();

                     if ($patientExists > 0) {

                        } else {

                            $patient = new Patient();
                            $patient->nom = $request->nom;
                            $patient->prenom = $request->prenom;
                            $patient->telephone = $request->telephone;
                            $patient->adresse = $request->adresse;
                            $patient->codePostale = $request->codePostale;
                            $patient->ville = $request->ville;
                            $patient->infoSupplementaire = $request->info;


                        if($patient->save()){


                            if($request->has('debut','fin')){


                             $dataOrdo=Validator::make($request->all(),[

                                 'dateOrdonnance'=>'required',

                             ]);
                                $datedebut = Carbon::parse($request->debut);
                                $datefin = Carbon::parse($request->fin);

                                $ordonnance=new Ordonnance();

                                $ordonnance->debut=$datedebut;
                                $ordonnance->fin=$datefin;
                                $ordonnance->patient_id=$patient->id;

                                if($ordonnance->save()){
                                 session()->put('id_ordonnance',$ordonnance->id);
                                 return['patient'=>$patient,'ordonnance'=>$ordonnance];

                                }

                            }
                        } ;



                             return response()->json([$request->all()]);
                        }

}
```